# Excel - For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro11()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'

'
Calculate
Range("B46:CRZ46").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B:B").Select
Cells(Range("B:B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

What the following Macro does, is refresh the page (which creates a new data set), copy the data set from `("B46:CRZ46")` and paste it in `"Sheet1"`.
Now, I want the pasting to go down a row every time (which I tried with `.End(xlUp)` however I am not using it correctly and it just copies and pastes on the same row.

What could I change or add to for the code to function well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign values directly without needing to copy/paste:

```
Dim rng As Range

Calculate

Set rng = Activesheet.Range("B46:CRZ46")

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp) _
       .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.rows.count, rng.columns.count).Value = rng.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the line:

```
Cells(Range("B:B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

with:

```
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

Explanation:

`Range("B:B").End(xlUp)` will take you to the top. Instead, the approach here should be to go to the bottom by `Range("B" & Rows.Count)` and then `End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` to go to 1 row below the 1st non-blank cell from bottom.